# Core Text and copy 'n paste on iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch

Is it possible in iOS to render complex text with CoreText and have copy 'n paste feature? I’ve found a lot of example about CoreText rendering but nothing that concerns copy 'n paste.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but you have to implement Copy & Paste yourself through use of [UIMenuController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Reference/UIMenuController_Class/UIMenuController.html). There is no 'built in' support in CoreText for Copy & Paste, as CoreText is a *very* low level library.

Answer (score 1):

RyanR is correct, there's no built in support in CoreText for Copy & Paste, but you can make your own copy & paste.

Take a look at this other topic post.

[Core Text - select text in iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7979592/is-it-possible-to-select-the-text-rendered-by-core-text-in-iphone/11005546#11005546)