# If I lay out text with Core Text, How can I add support to 'copy/paste'?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, cocoa, core-text

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Core Text and copy 'n paste on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6495838/core-text-and-copy-n-paste-on-ios)

If I lay out text with Core Text, How can I add support to 'copy/paste'? I can't select the text.