# Core Text - select text in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, core-text

I need to render rich text using Core Text in my view (simple formatting, multiple fonts in one line of texts, etc.). I am wondering if text rendered this way can be selected by user using (standard copy / paste function)?

Comment: it would be nice if @javsmo answer was selected instead of the current one. It has 7 up votes

Comment: I know, it is a very nice answer but it showed few months after selected answer (which also answered my question). I am not sure if this would be fair...

Comment: since the original responder deleted it's answer

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I implemented a text selection in CoreText. It is really a hard work... But it's doable.

Basically you have to save all `CTLine` rects and origins using `CTFrameGetLineOrigins`<sup>(1)</sup>, `CTLineGetTypographicBounds`<sup>(2)</sup>, `CTLineGetStringRange`<sup>(3)</sup> and `CTLineGetOffsetForStringIndex`<sup>(4)</sup>.

The line rect can be calculated using the origin<sup>(1)</sup>, ascent<sup>(2)</sup>, descent<sup>(2)</sup> and offset<sup>(3)(4)</sup> as shown bellow.

```
lineRect = CGRectMake(origin.x + offset, 
                      origin.y - descent, 
                      offset, 
                      ascent + descent);
```

After doing that, you can test which line has the touched point looping the lines (always remember that CoreText uses inverse Y coordinates).

Knowing the line that has the touched point, you can know the letter that is located at that point (or the nearest letter) using `CTLineGetStringIndexForPosition`.

Here's one screenshot.

[image: selecting text drawn with CoreText]

For that loupe, I used the code [shown in this post](http://coffeeshopped.com/2010/03/a-simpler-magnifying-glass-loupe-view-for-the-iphone).

**Edit:**
To draw the blue background selection, you have to paint the rect using `CGContextFillRect`. Unfortunately, there's no background color in `NSAttributedString`.

Comment: Hi javsmo, your example looks brilliant! Any chance you could send me some source code? Many thanks. Tom

Comment: Thanks, @TomTom . My code to draw text and do the selections with CoreText has almost 500 lines. It's complicated to post it without any explain. Which part of selection are you having trouble with?

Comment: Hi javsmo 。you are so great,I hope you share to us.maybe use github and so on....Thanks...

Comment: @PareshNavadiya do you have any sample, i can add magnifier view only, after that i dont have any idea?

Comment: this is 8 years ago but did you draw the handles or make those layers and just update the rects?  I am implementing something similar to this right now.  I have the drawing done but not the handles and their movements.

Comment: Everything was drawn in that case, including the handles. In the end it was simply a vertical line with two concentric circles. The app still uses that code, but I believe there should be something already written to solve this problem.