# How to select text from coretext view?

Tags: ios7, core-graphics, core-text

I want a UIMenucontroller like toolbar in my core text view so that I can able to copy the text.

Since very long time I'm searching some code for making selection over the text in core text view. I tried some answer given in stackoverflow like https://stackoverflow.com/a/11005546/1304896 but did not get any right direction.

Could you please help me out from this problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what exactly want you to achieve, but I can suggest you to look in [EGOTextView](https://github.com/enormego/EGOTextView) code.
This is working version of full editable core text view.
You need to browse through this code to understand how exactly the UIMenu and selection is implemented.